# Server is not booting after attempting to mount a disk

Tags: boot, server, partitioning, mount

I was trying to mount a 10Tb disk on a ubuntu server. Due to the large size of the disk I had to use **parted** instead of **fdisk**. 
Unfortunately I did not enable **GPT support** in Linux kernel, prior to mounting the disk.
Upon restarting the server, it does not boot up. My initial thought was, that it is a  problem with grub, so I attempted to reinstall the grub2 on :

```
[*] /dev/sda
[*] /dev/sdb
```

Using the below commands:

```
apt-get install --reinstall grub-pc
dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```

But later on I fount it online  that:

> If you don’t add GPT support in Linux kernel, after rebooting the
>   server, the file system will no longer be mountable, or the GPT table
>   will get corrupted.

I am able to get access to the system using the rescue service offered by the host provider. Which is a linux system based on Debian. Below are the output of the df -h and fdisk -l commands that I get from the rescue Linux service:

```
#df -ha
 Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
proc                    0     0     0    - /proc
sys                     0     0     0    - /sys
udev                  32G     0   32G   0% /dev
devpts                  0     0     0    - /dev/pts
SERVER'S_IP_ADDRESS:/nfs  295G  124G  156G  45% /root/.oldroot/nfs
overlay               32G  116K   32G   1% /
securityfs              0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/security
tmpfs                 32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
devpts                  0     0     0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs                 32G   13M   32G   1% /run
tmpfs                5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                 32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgroup                  0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
cgroup                  0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct
cgroup                  0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
cgroup                  0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
cgroup                  0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
cgroup                  0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
cgroup                  0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
cgroup                  0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/pids
cgroup                  0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event
systemd-1               0     0     0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
hugetlbfs               0     0     0    - /dev/hugepages
mqueue                  0     0     0    - /dev/mqueue
tmpfs                6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/0  


#fdisk -l
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/loop0: 3 GiB, 3221225472 bytes, 6291456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x04cbff79

Device     Boot    Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           2048   33556479  33554432    16G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2       33556480   34605055   1048576   512M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3       34605056 1000213167 965608112 460.4G fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/sdc: 9.1 TiB, 10000831348736 bytes, 19532873728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x4686096e

Device     Boot    Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           2048   33556479  33554432    16G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2       33556480   34605055   1048576   512M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3       34605056 1000213167 965608112 460.4G fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/md0: 16 GiB, 17163091968 bytes, 33521664 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/md1: 511.4 MiB, 536281088 bytes, 1047424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/md2: 460.3 GiB, 494257111040 bytes, 965345920 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

How can I address this issue?

> Server: ubuntu-16.04.6-server
>
> Provider: Hetzner

Comment: Did you add an entry for the 10TB disk in /etc/fstab ? If you did, you may have to remove that entry before the system will boot

Comment: I did. But now under the rescue booting, that file is empty.

Comment: That file definitely shouldn't be empty. It should contain the entries for the boot drive and another for "/"

Comment: I checked it again, it is empty. The rescue system is like a live CD sort of thing, with some volumes being mounted to the system. The actual  /etc/fstab file, when the server was running had few lines of configurations in it, including the one i added for the disk. but now when I  " cat  /etc/fstab" , it only shows an empty file.

Comment: Are you looking at the /etc/fstab file from the Rescue System or the one on your actual system? Be sure you are looking at the right one.

Comment: You were right, the /etc/fstab was from the rescue system, I had to mount the actual ones and check the /etc/fstab on the main drive. The problem is solved. Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by removing the original entry in the `/etc/fstab` file for the 10TB filesystem of the original (not the rescue) system.

For anyone else visiting this question in the future: Use an Ubuntu bootable USB stick or recovery environment and:

- mount the filesystem of your original boot drive
- use a text editor to remove the entry that you make for the partition/drive that is causing problems in `/etc/fstab`.

Once that entry is removed the machine should boot.

Comment: An edit and an upvote!  **;-)** Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1161358/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**

Comment: Will do Fabby! Thank you!